# Can one surfaceview handle multiple rounds

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a game I am developing and currently I have one surfaceview class that handles one round which ends after you shoot the correct image from the screen. I want to know if i need to have another class to handle getting new images for the next round, or could i just call this class again after the round ends and get the new data pushed to this same class. Currently I finish the activity then call itself again which results in crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `SurfaceView` ought to be enough for everybody.

Please, make sure you separate your game logic from UI, so when your user changes from one level to another, your application just reloads the necessary resources and keeps going on instead of destroying and recreating all activities.

Comment: This is what I need guidance with, how to I request the new resources for the next round to keep the game going?

Comment: Do i need to setup a middle class to do this properly?

Comment: basically you need one `SurfaceView` to display things to your user, a few classes related to gameplay and AI, and several asynchronous helpers (`AsyncTask`s) to offload resource loading into the background threads. that's pretty much all. please, see some game samples from SDK.